# How to display Redux Framework options in theme

Tags: php, redux-framework

Im new with Redux Framework and Im removing propanel and Im adding Redux instead but the options now not working

For example an exsisting option in my theme for related videos:

```
<?php 
$relatedvideosbase = get_option('mytheme_relatedvideos');
if ($relatedvideosbase == "tags") {
get_template_part( 'related/tags', get_post_format() ); 
} elseif ($relatedvideosbase == "category") { 
get_template_part( 'related/category', get_post_format() ); 
} elseif ($relatedvideosbase == "random") { 
get_template_part( 'related/random', get_post_format() );
} else {
get_template_part( 'related/tags', get_post_format() ); 
}   
?>
```

The Above code was working fine with propanel and I removed propanel now added the redux framework and Created the option like this:

```
    array(
        'id'       => '_relatedvideos',
        'type'     => 'button_set',
        'title'    => __( 'Related Videos by?', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
        //Must provide key => value pairs for radio options
        'options'  => array(
             'tags' => __('Tags','redux-framework-demo'),
            'category' => __('Category','redux-framework-demo'),
            'random' => __('Random','redux-framework-demo')
        ),
        'default'  => 'random'
    ),
```

Changed also the opt name as I had in propanel `$opt_name = 'mytheme';` but with redux framework I cant figure it out, is there any way ? thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the global $redux_demo before your code like below

```
global $redux_demo; // This is your opt_name.
```

and to echo the option

```
echo $redux_demo['the option id'];
```

change the $redux_demo to your option name and change the option id to your option id

https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/getting-started/

Comment: This does not work in redux framework 4.0 +, can you update your answer?